# delete by primary key takes forever mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to delete by primary key from Table (300 rows) and it takes up to max query execution time and at the end returns `ERROR 2013: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. This table has foreign key to the large table (200k rows). What can be an issue?
Query: `DELETE FROM Table Where table_id=x`
EDIT:
There are no triggers associated with this DELETE statement. DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE statements in some database tables work really slow while SELECT statements in whole database work perfectly fine.
EDIT#2:
Additional information from innodb trx table for the query:
`trx_lock_structs 429704`
`trx_lock_memmory_bytes 34698792`
`trx_rows_locked 214938`
`trx_isolation_level REPEATABLE READ`
`trx_unique_checks 1`
`trx_foreign_key_checks 1`
This query deletes 1 row and doesn't have child rows, why locked rows value is so high?

EDIT#3
Investigating situation further I have determined that tables that have slow insert/update/delete operations are the tables that have foreign key with the big table (200k). Is it necessary to remove this foreign keys or data integrity is more important? Although 200k rows is not that much what can be reasons for this slow operations?

EDIT#4
SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table` (
`table_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tableb_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`tablec_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`bigtable_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`table_id`),
 KEY `fk_tableb_id_idx` (`tableb_id`),
 KEY `fk_bigtable_id_idx` (`bigtable_id`),
 KEY `fk_tablec_id_idx` (`tablec_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_bigtable_id` FOREIGN KEY (`bigtable_id`) REFERENCES `Bigtable`  
 (`bigtable_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_tableb_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tableb_id`) REFERENCES `tablebs`  
 (`tableb_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_tablec_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tablec_id`) REFERENCES `tablecs`    
 (`tablec_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=271 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

BigTable is a typical Users table id and additional information.
EDIT#5
EXPLAIN DELETE:
`select_type` : SIMPLE,
`table` : Table,
`type`  : range,
`possible_keys` : PRIMARY,
`key` : PRIAMRY,
`key_len` : 8,
`ref` : const,
`rows` : 1,
`Extra` : Using where

Comment: So, foreign key constraints are defined with an action to take in the event that the parent record is deleted.  If the defined action is `CASCADE`, then associated child records are also deleted; this cascade could carry on through thousands of records and might very well mean that the explicit deletion of just a single record is ultimately very slow indeed.

Comment: do you have, on the large table, an index on the foreign key field to this table?

Comment: I am deleting child record so no other child records involved.

Comment: Foreign key is a primary key in a large table

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know what we are dealing with.

Comment: @RickJames provided `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: When deleting "300" rows, how many other rows will be deleted due to `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: @RickJames It depends on a row. It can "possibly" have up to 100 rows. But with this amount of data this scenario never occurs and each of this row has maximum of 2-3 rows

Comment: So, maybe a total of 600 rows deleted across 5 tables.  How long is "forever"?  Are you running 5.6; if so please provide `EXPLAIN DELETE ...`

Comment: No fair!  Your DELETE says `WHERE id=x`, but there is no `id` in the table definition.  _Please_ be consistent in your obfuscation.  Are there other typos like that?

Comment: @RickJames DELETE was just a meta code to show that I am deleting by primary key. In a create table I provided style it would look `Delete FROM Table where table_id=x`   
Explain delete provided in question.

Comment: Just an oddball question: have you verified that the hard disk that the tables are stored on is good, and that there is no file-level corruption going on?

Comment: Have you tried setting all the foreign keys to NULL, and then deleting the records? Is this faster? If so, you can then use the same method to identify WHICH foreign key is responsible, and narrow down the problem that way.

Comment: @KevinKeane yes, I have checked the hard disk and tables for corruption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is cascade on big table. Do you understand the complexity of this computation? it is not just a delete operation on 300 rows. It is basically 300 rows * 200k. Each delete would go and pass through the big table and would perform delete operation on the corresponding rows (based on the id).

Just follow the below mentioned steps:

```
1) Remove the references of this primary id of this table from other tables (if any)
2) Alter this table and add NO ACTION to the UPDATE & CASCADE of big table foreign key 
   OR 
   remove all the foreign key contraints
3) delete from tableName
```

Comment: For example, If I have key from Table A to Table B and if I am deleting row from table A than MySQL will pass through Table B? Isn't it other way around?

Comment: @RuslanN if tablea_id is as used in tableB ...and in table b you have set on cascade delete for tablea_id... that means, when you would delete a row in tableA, corresponding records will be deleted from table B.

Comment: @Yes, If I had foreign key from small table in my big table with `CASCADE` this could be a reason

Comment: yes and this is what you are doing @RuslanN 300 records points to the table of 200k records :) .

Comment: @RuslanN let me know your findings.. I will be waiting

Comment: I have provided with bounty answer that is more helpful because it helps to analyse the problem. I have marked your post as answer because it provides some steps but doesn't explain reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest an empirical approach...

Delete ops with cascade impacts on indexes, slow execution time may depend on time needed to elaborate fKey indexes, btw your tables aren't huge. You say you have no triggers, functions or procedure, so you have to benchmark your query to find what's part is taking so much time...
I assume that you have already verified indexes efficency.

So to benchmark your delete query you should handy write "inner deletion" queries and benchmark each one, using `BENCHMARK()`.

This way you will find which part of that deletion took so long.

What if each single part is reasonably fast?

You may have some misconfiguration in your my.cnf, so you could try checking with https://tools.percona.com/wizard recommendations...
Maybe you have some memory allocation limit or some thread/memory limit.
You can find many tutorials on mysql optimization like http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/optimizing-mysql-server-settings/

You can also find some scripts that may help you in finding mysql optimizations.

Without knowing your architecture, mysql configuration and your database structure, it's quite hard to give a 100% solution, but I hope you can find the way, I'll be glad to read about your findings. If something more will come to my mind I'll keep you posted.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question but gives some solid advices. I am going to mark this as an answer if no one else will answer.